# Spring Batch Upgrade Version 1 to 4

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-aop, spring-framework-beans

I'm upgrading Spring Batch version 1 to 4, and I'm getting this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [simple-job-launcher-context.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5170bcf4' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5170bcf4': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2812b107' of type [org.springframework.aop.config.MethodLocatingFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2812b107': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.batch.sample.advice.ProcessorLogAdvice] for bean with name 'logAdvice' defined in class path resource [simple-job-launcher-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.sample.advice.ProcessorLogAdvice
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dao.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager] for bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dao.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.batch.sample.advice.ProcessorLogAdvice] for bean with name 'logAdvice' defined in class path resource [simple-job-launcher-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.sample.advice.ProcessorLogAdvice
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.batch.sample.advice.MethodExecutionApplicationEventAdvice] for bean with name 'eventAdvice' defined in class path resource [simple-job-launcher-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.sample.advice.MethodExecutionApplicationEventAdvice
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:236)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:709)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:534)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at ph.pnblife.julia.batch.Main.runBatch(Main.java:56)
    at ph.pnblife.julia.batch.Main.main(Main.java:48)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5170bcf4' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5170bcf4': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2812b107' of type [org.springframework.aop.config.MethodLocatingFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2812b107': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.batch.sample.advice.ProcessorLogAdvice] for bean with name 'logAdvice' defined in class path resource [simple-job-launcher-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.sample.advice.ProcessorLogAdvice
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:327)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:632)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:107)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:491)
```

and this is my xml file.

```xml
<bean id="jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor"
  class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobLauncher"
  class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="taskExecutor">
      <bean class="org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jobRegistry"
  class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" />
```

Comment: You jumped 4 major versions, have you attempted to move to 1 > 2 > 3 > 4 reading the changelog along the way to ease the issues?

Comment: The general guidance is that if you need to upgrade more than 1 major version, you should look to do a rewrite, not an upgrade. As someone who went from 2 to 4, I can't argue with that.